# How to edit or remove cookies in Firefox DevTools?

Tags: cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

In Firebug I am able to remove and edit any cookies using the *Cookies* panel.

But in the Firefox DevTools I can't find any way to remove or edit cookies.

[image: *Network* panel in Firefox DevTools showing request cookies]

Where can I do that?

Comment: Firebug is discontinued. What you are seeing are the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) with a Firebug theme. See the related [Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Zartner!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To edit cookies in the Firefox DevTools you have to ensure the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) is enabled via the [settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings).

[image: Storage Inspector in settings panel]

Within the Storage Inspector you'll then be able to edit existing cookies by double-clicking the values within the list:

[image: Editing cookie value]

You can also remove cookies by right-clicking them and choosing one of the options from the context menu.

[image: Deleting cookies]

Also, an [option to add cookies](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1231452) was added in Firefox 55. To add one, either right-click the list of cookies and choose *Add Item* or click the + button in the panel toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for an awesome answer!

Comment: I'm happy that I could help!

Comment: You may also see a bug where it does not appear to be deleted, but you just need to close and reopen devtools. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1467463

Answer (score 5):

I was having problems adding cookies in Firefox 65 and came here from Google.

My problem was that I could not add new cookies. I was using a *Private Window*. Using a normal (non-private) window however, I was able to add new cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox 94 and have the same issue as @Tmarty when using **Private Window**.

To bypass this issue, simply press F5 to refresh the page after adding cookies. The new cookies will show up and can be edited. Below are some screenshots:

1. The cookie list does not change after adding a new cookie
   [image: before-refresh]
2. After refreshing the page, the cookie list is updated and you can edit the new cookie
   [image: after-refresh]