# How to delete cookies in firefox devtools?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I can not delete cookies in firefox devtools. When I clicked any of the "Delete ..." drop-down menu items, nothing happened. Does anybody know how to do delete the cookies in devtools? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You may be seeing a bug: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011964/how-to-edit-or-remove-cookies-in-firefox-devtools#comment108836486_42013295) says: You may also see a bug where it does not appear to be deleted, but you just need to close and reopen devtools [bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1467463](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1467463)

Comment: If it hinders your workflow, there are cookie manager add-ons available.

Comment: Hello, I think you need to revisit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions also should come with a [minimal, but complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Reviewing 20 of your latest questions, they're mostly off-topic for StackOverflow. Some of them should be asked on SuperUser or other SE communities but not SO. Cheers.